# Mvc area routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, area

My project structure:

```
Controller
    AdminController
    HomeController
```

After Area addition my project structureI added an Admin area to project,

```
Areas
    Admin
        Controller
            SomeController
Controller
    AdminController
    HomeController
```

then all links are broken. For example

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "go to some action", 
    "SomeAction", 
    "Admin", 
    new { area = "" }, 
    null)
```

When I write above link, it routes me to `www.myDomain.com/Admin/SomeAction`, but this is Area action, I want to route to AdminController action.

How can I do this? Should I change Area or Controller name?

**Update**

above link output:

```
domain/Admin/SomeAction
// I expect that is AdminController/SomeAction
// but not. There is SomeAction in my admin controller
// I get this error "The resource cannot be found."
// because it looks my expected, but it works unexpected
// it tries to call AdminArea/SomeController/SomeAction
```

**Update 2**

for example:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(
    "go to some action", 
    "SomeAnotherAction", 
    "Admin", 
    new { area = "" }, 
    null)
```

for above link I dont get any error, because I have a SomeAnotherAction in my area.

Area registeration

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: You'l have to route it to the Controller that has SomeAction in it. Right now you are calling the SomeAction ActionResult from the AdminController. You want to call SomeAction from the AreaController. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Edited. It is difficult to explain for me, too. Summary, I want to call project main controller action, but it calls area controller action. And link looks correct, but it works incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have registered your areas first, they are taking precedence. There's no easy way around this. The best solution would be to rename your `AccountController` in the main part of the site to something else in order to avoid the conflict.

Another possibility is to constrain the controllers in your Area route registration:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { controller = "Some|SomeOther" }
);
```

Now only requests to `/Admin/Some/{action}` or `/Admin/SomeOther/{action}` will be routed to the area, meaning that `/Admin/SomeAction` will be intercepted by the global route definition and routed to your `AdminController`.

Comment: second way is working, but it is not elegant way, because I should all area controllers, right? if yes I will change my admin controller name... Thanks for advice...